# Eclipse Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to install eclipse on my machine with Jave version 16. While installing I'm getting the below error. Any suggestions to overcome this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
!SESSION 2021-07-20 18:46:53.334 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400`enter code here`
java.version=16
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-07-20 18:49:04.893
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2021-07-20 18:49:04.964
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 21 more
!SESSION 2021-07-21 12:48:24.183 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=16
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-07-21 12:48:33.116
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2021-07-21 12:48:33.166
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 21 more
!SESSION 2021-07-21 13:08:07.954 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=16
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-07-21 13:08:09.590
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2021-07-21 13:08:09.606
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy 
cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 21 more
```

Comment: You are not actually asking a question and assuming that you want to prevent this exception from being thrown, we have to guess what you did to get this exception. Please update your question following these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7):

Your system has java16 installed. You're attempting to install an Eclipse version that does not support it - seems to be a problem with Eclipse documentation, they specify "Java 8 or newer", where in reality those builds can't work with java11 or newer.

You can either downgrade Java to version 8, or you can download a newer build of Eclipse that supports java11 and newer (Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09) or later)

Comment: I got the same issue, that the eclipse give me an error message when I try to open it, I didn't do anything, but there are some updates that happened. so I checked the Environment Variable in Windows, and saw that the java version was changed from 8 to 11. i downgraded it to 8 again, and eclipse opened normally.

Comment: Thanks to Deltharis, you can find how to downgrade jdk in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133216/downgrading-java-11-to-java-8/1133226#1133226

Comment: Thank you for this in answer. I tried "cleaning" various eclipse settings. Then I saw your answer. In my Case it happened I installed Visual Studio. I must have selected Java inadvertently. It had installed and put JDK 11 up on PATH. This caused Eclipse to fail. Removed it from Env PATH variable, all good now.

Comment: Had the same issue and, as fairly suggested above, I traced back my actions.  While setting up VS Code I upgraded java from 8 to 11 - breaking my Eclipse Neon workspace (same exception). I reverted env vars for JAVA_HOME and PATH from 11 back to 8 and my eclipse started loading again. So now I know how to fix such an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue with Scala IDE 4.7.0 on Ubuntu 4.22 system. My system installed with JDK-11. System is throwing mentioned exceptions in Eclipse logs.
I downgrade JDK from 11 to JDK 9 but issue remains as it was.
Again I downgrade JDK from 9 to JDK 8. Now Scala IDE is running fine on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue due to installing Java 17. Fixed it by creating an eclipse.bat that does two things:

1. `set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_8_HOME%`
2. `set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`

That seems to have fixed the issue and it still leaves Java 17 usable.